# How to write sqlcmd results directly to Azure Storage using Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure-storage, sqlcmd, azure-powershell, azure-sql-database

Current story:

Moving overall BI solution fully to Azure cloud services. Building a new Azure DW and loading data from an Azure DB. Currently, Azure DW doesn't support linked servers and/or the elastic query (this is only supported in Azure DB). Due to price, we can **not** use data factory or an instance of SSIS. We **can't** use bcp as we don't have a local directory to hold the file in between loads.

Is it possible to use Azure PowerShell with sqlcmd to write results of a query directly to Azure Storage, without having to write to a file on a local directory in between?

Are there other options that aren't mentioned above?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

The current Azure Storage PowerShell (Set-AzureStorageBlobContent) only support upload blob from local file.

Azure Storage Client Library (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) support to upload blob from stream, can you try to develop your own application with the  Azure Storage Client Library?

If your data is big, you can also try https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/, it has better performance in upload big blob.